# how to read values from a file inside gitlab-ci yml

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Trying to read values from a file inside gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
- IN_FILE="base_dir/apps_namespaces.txt"
- echo "IN_FILE = " > $IN_FILE 
- while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do 
-   echo "Name read from file - " > $line
- done < $IN_FILE
```

But this script fails with error -  `"/usr/bin/bash: line 131: read: line: invalid number"`

Whereas same logic works in a plain script file, having following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
done < "$1"
```

when ran this script using command : `./scrpt apps_namespaces.txt`

it rans and print each line.

What can be done if needs a long list to be read inside a gitlab-ci yml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you can emulate this [`gitlab-ci.yml` loop example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60996973/6309), which:

- does not include the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`)
- does not have a - in front of each line

```yaml
  script:
    [...]
    - while read line; do
         echo $line;
         ./sireg-linux exec --loader-sitemap-sitemap \"$line\" >> ./output/${line##*/}_out.txt;
      done < sitemap-index
```

Of course, the alternative is to put the logic in a script, called from the pipeline, as documented in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 2672](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2672)

> This is basic Unix, you just need your script to be executable in your git repo
>
> ```sh
> chmod a+x scripts/test.sh
> git add scripts/test.sh
> git commit "fixing permissions"
> git push
> ```
>
> don't put `/usr/bin/env` for `sh` nor `bash`: both are 100% guaranteed to be present as `#! /bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` if `bash` is installed, or at least a much guaranteed to be there than `/usr/bin/env` to exists (and using `env sh` is not very good security)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach which I followed:

put the logic to read file contents inside a script file. And refer this script inside gitlab-ci.yml worked.

It is cleaner and manageable.

Comment: I tried inline scripting as you suggested by removing "-" and removed shebang (#!/bin/bash), but seems some issue with gitlab-ci. It keep on giving same error. The same logic when kept in separate file and run as script works. That's why I used that as script inside gitlab-ci yml.