# Import external yaml file and use them as environment variable in GITLAB

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a rest_config.yaml file which looks loke this:

```
host: abcd
apiKey: abcd
secretKey: abcd
```

I want to import these in my .gitlab-ci.yaml file and use them as my environment variable. How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

If your yaml file is part of the checked out repository on which the gitlab-ci.yaml pipeline operates, said pipeline can read the file in a `script:` section, as [I illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66559986/6309).

That script: section can set [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415116/6309).
And [you can pass variables explicitly between jobs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22638#note_437143346)

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - VAR1=foo
  - VAR2=bar
  - echo export VAR1="${VAR1}" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/variables
  - echo export VAR2="${VAR2}" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/variables
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - variables

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - source $CI_PROJECT_DIR/variables
  - echo VAR1 is $VAR1
  - echo VAR2 is $VAR2
```

Answer (score 0):

build:
stage: build
script: - VAR1=foo

- echo export VAR2="${VAR2}" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/variables
  artifacts:
  paths:

  - variables

test:
stage: test
script:

- source $CI_PROJECT_DIR/variables

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).